# php week interval from date ("W")

Tags: php, date, intervals

Hy, I have in database number of the week `date ("W")` and I want to display week interval like `28 Jan -> 3 Feb` in this format, and I don't know if it's possible. Can you help?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: not much, I was thinking how to introduce direct current week interval instead of week number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$year = 2013;
$week_no = 6;

$week_start = new DateTime();
$week_start->setISODate($year,$week_no);
$week_end = clone $week_start;
$week_end = $week_end->add(new DateInterval("P1W"));

echo $week_start->format('d-M-Y') . " - ".$week_end->format('d-M-Y');
```

Comment: DateTime->__construct()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/week.php on line 5

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct()

Comment: sorry, wrote it down without testing it. now it works (php 5.3+)

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/XXXXXX');
no it works, thank you for your help

Comment: @Cipi; As a portal rule, "if an answer helped you so worked for you, so you need to accept it pushing accept button"..

Comment: @Cipi; No, you said "it works" at prev comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608747/php-week-interval-from-date-w/14609023#comment20401320_14609023).

Comment: I really do not see one, I may have eye problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Transform your intervals into timestamps.

If its not the first day of the week get the first day of that week with strtotime "last sunday" (or monday) for the first date.

Do the same for the second date this time geting the last day of the week with "next saturday" (or sunday);

Get both dates W and make a mysql comparison between the weeks.